# Prove $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}u(x,t)=0$ under some conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $f(x)$ be bounded and continuous for $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and satisfy $\int |f(y)| dy < \infty.$ Prove that there exists a solution $u(x,t)$ of
$$
\begin{array}{l}
u_t=\Delta u, \text{ for $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $t>0$,} \\ 
u=f(x), \text{ for $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $t=0$,}
\end{array}
$$
such that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}u(x,t)=0$ How can I prove this?

I think it we know $f$ is bounded and continuous, then use the fundamental solution of heat equation. We have if we consider $t$ goes to infinite the solution will decreases exponentially to 0. Is this right? If right, what $\int |f(y)| dy < \infty$ is do? Since I didn't use it in mine proof.

If not, how can I prove that? And where I am wrong?

Comment: If $\int|f(y)|dy$ isn't finite the problem isn't well posed (It doesn't have a unique solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded and continuous, one may use the fundamental solution to the heat equation to write the solution to the IVP as
$$
u(x,t)=(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}f(y)\,dy. \tag{1}
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
0\leq |u(x,t)|&\leq (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}|f(y)|\,dy \\
&\leq (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|\,dy. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|\,dy<\infty$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}(4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(y)|\,dy=0. \tag{3}
$$
Finally, from $(2)$ and $(3)$ one may conclude that $\lim_{t\to\infty}u(x,t)=0.\quad\square$

Comment: In $(2)$ why the term of exponential dissappear?

Comment: Because $e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}\leq 1$ if $t>0$.

Comment: From the comment says that $\int|f(y)|dy$ is use to check it unique, but how can I connect it to $C(R^n)$ intersection $L^∞$, in particular the last term, how can I check that to make it met uniqueness theorem?

Comment: One need not assume $\int |f(y)|\,dy<\infty$ to prove uniqueness of the solution to the heat equation; much weaker conditions are sufficient. See, for instance, this [paper](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Ji.pdf).

Comment: The $(2)$ also prove the uniqueness, right? That is to prove $|u(x,t)| \leq Ae^{a|x|^2}$.

Comment: Boundedness of $f$ is enough: $$|f(x)|\leq M\implies |u(x,t)| \leq (4\pi t)^{-n/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}M\,dy=M\leq Ae^{a|x|^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. I found that the exercise is exist a solution not to find unique solution while is also true.